# Problemas ao consumir REST pelo meu App

Tags: c#, android, rest, xamarin

Em realidade fiz no lado do serviço(que está funcionando) eu estou serializando uma lista, mas na verdade é apenas um único valor retornado. Para esse serviço eu tenho apenas uma informação, um valor decimal, mas tentei colocar uma **Task** simples e um retorno **FirstOrDefault** e dá erro. Bem, então mantive a **List** mesmo sabendo que não é a forma correta, mas vou alterar isso. O que preciso nesse momento é fazer meu **App Android(Xamarin.Forms)** consumir esse serviço. Ele está se perdendo. Pelo **Postman** ok, está funcionando meu REST, mas pelo **App** é que não funfa. Veja os códigos no meu **App**.

Fiz uma model exatamente com é no lado do serviço. Essa **Model** é exatamente idêntica à **Model** que está no REST, tudo.

```
public class DesvioFaturamento
    {
        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public int IdGaragem { get; set; }
        public decimal Desvio { get; set; }
    }
```

Aí fiz uma classe para Desserializar o que o serviço que fornece

```
public class DataService
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public async Task<List<DesvioFaturamento>> getDesvioFaturamento(int user, int garagem)
        {
            string url = $"http://localhost:2710/api/faturamento/{user}/{garagem}";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var desvio = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DesvioFaturamento>>(response);
            return desvio;
        }
    }
```

E na minha MainPage.xaml.cs fiz o métod(click) que pega o que o serviço me disponibiliza assim:

```
try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGaragem.Text))
                {
                    int user = Int32.Parse(txtUser.Text);
                    int garagem = Int32.Parse(txtGaragem.Text);
                    var data = await dataService.getDesvioFaturamento(user, garagem);
                    DesvioFatNotifications.Text = data.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string erro = ex.Message;
            }
```

O **var data...** está quebrando. Quando chega nesse ponto não faz nada e preciso fechar o debug, senão fica sem nenhuma resposta. Claro não esperei mais do que 2 min, enfim, não funciona. Como consumir esse serviço?

**EDIT1**

Tentando resolver isso, eu coloquei essas linhas em meu projeto.

```
response.Wait(); // use assim ou com o while ....

                while (response.Status != System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {

                }
```

Está dando erro que:

> "string" não contem uma definição para Wait e não foi encontrar nenhum
>   método de extensão "Wait"...

Tenho uma outra App que não tenho erro nessas linhas e tenho as mesmas referências e etc...

**EDIT2**

Meu serviço está assim(Model):

```
[Route("faturamento/{iduser}/{idgaragem}")]
        public List<decimal> GetDesvioFaturamento(int iduser, int idgaragem)
        {
            var desvio = lista.Where(l => l.IdUsuario == iduser && l.IdGaragem == idgaragem)
                        .Select(s => s.Desvio).ToList();

            return desvio;
        }
```

Minha controller(ApiController)

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Faturamento")]
    public class FaturamentoController : ApiController
    {
        DesvioFaturamentoModel desvio = new DesvioFaturamentoModel();

        [Route("{iduser}/{idgaragem}")]
        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<decimal> GetDesvioFaturamento(int iduser, int idgaragem)
        {
            return desvio.GetDesvioFaturamento(iduser, idgaragem);
        }
    }
```

Minha classe POCO

```
public class DesvioFaturamento
    {
        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public int IdGaragem { get; set; }
        public decimal Desvio { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT3**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT4**

Fiz esse novo código

```
try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2710/api/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

                //string url = $"faturamento/{user}/{garagem}";
                string url = $"http://localhost:2710/api/faturamento/{user}/{garagem}";
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url));

                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);


                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DesvioFaturamento>>(json.Result);
                    }
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    string erro = ex.Message;
                }

                return null;
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                string erro = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }
```

e na linha do `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);`está dando esse erro:

> An error occurred while sending the request

praticamente não diz nada

**EDIT5**

Tenho esse código em meu dataservice

```
try
            {
                client = new HttpClient();
                string url = $"http://localhost:2710/api/faturamento/{IdUsuario}/{IdGaragem}";
                try
                {
                    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                    var desvio = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DesvioFaturamento>>(response);
                    return desvio.ToList();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
```

Quando chega nessa linha `var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);` o app para e não sei mais o que acontece. Não cai no catch interno que coloquei.

Comment: hehehe seu erro esta no seu  var desvio = lista.Where(l => l.IdUsuario == iduser && l.IdGaragem == idgaragem)
                        .Select(s => s.Desvio).ToList();

Comment: bem aqui  .Select(s => s.Desvio)

Comment: ai vocÊ faz um  var desvio = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DesvioFaturamento>>(response);

Comment: é o que retorna é uma lista de Desvio e não o tipo esperado ou seja List<DesvioFaturamento>

Comment: veja seu proprio print que só tem um 99 e não sua classe

Comment: Então, estou com essa dúvida desde ontem. O que preciso seria retornar apenas o valor esperado e não estava conseguindo. No lugar de retornar um IEnumerable<decimal> deveria retornar a minha classe, certo, @MarconcilioSouza

Comment: Não sei, vai da sua regra de negocio, o que você tem que saber é que tem que DeserializeObject para o mesmo tipo que você esta mandando. se você vai manda uma lista de DesvioFaturamento tem que  DeserializeObject  para uma lista do mesmo tipo ...

Comment: O que esta retornando no seu var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url); ??? você vai precisar so do Desvio

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, então fiz isso e está vindo nula minha lista. Fiz uma alteração e quando chega nessa linha o sistema para: `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);`

Answer (score 0):

Tem alguns detalhes faltando no método que busca os dados da API. Vou modificar seu método para a forma que utilizo aqui e funciona perfeitamente.

```
public async Task<List<DesvioFaturamento>> GetDesvioFaturamento(int user, int garagem)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2710/api/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string url = $"faturamento/{user}/{garagem}";

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DesvioFaturamento>>(json.Result);
    }

    return null;
}
```

#### Observações

- Note que eu uso a propriedade `BaseAddress` para definir a URL base da sua API. Do jeito que estava fazendo também funciona, mas essa é a forma recomendada (boas práticas) para esse tipo de operação.
- Adicionei um header à sua requisição: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));`

#### Timeout

Caso queira, é possível definir um timeout para a sua requisição. Para isso, basta adicionar a seguinte linha abaixo de `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));`:

```
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
```

Feito isso, após 60 segundos sem resultado, o método irá retornar uma exceção do tipo `TaskCanceledException`.

```
public async Task<List<DesvioFaturamento>> GetDesvioFaturamento(int user, int garagem)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2710/api/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

        string url = $"faturamento/{user}/{garagem}";

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DesvioFaturamento>>(json.Result);
        }

        return null;
     }
     catch(TaskCanceledException ex)
     {
        /// TODO
     }
}
```

Comment: Quando chega nessa linha `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);` para. Tive esse problema antes e resolvi com o `Wait()` que coloquei em minha edição e que agora não está aceitando e não sei porque.

Comment: Coloca o timeout conforme falei ali em cima e adicione um try catch no método e verifique se é gerada uma exceção por timeout. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Cara, quando chega na linha acima para tudo. Não trava, mas nada acontece, como se ele estivesse se perdido. Vou editar e postar o código do serviço, mas adianto que testando pelo Postman eu obtenho o resultado esperado.

Comment: Coloca um breakpoint na linha if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) e outro breakpoint no catch(TaskCanceledException ex) e veja se o código chega ali pelo menos. E outra, o endereço usado no postman está igual ao código? A sua API está online no endereço localhost informado?

Comment: O postman está exatamente como eu estou. O problema é que não chega nessas linhas. Já fiz isso e não chega. Quando chega na linha citada, para e não faz mais nada. Preciso dar um Kill. URL do Postman copiado e colado: http://localhost:2710/api/faturamento/1/1

Comment: Teria como colocar uma imagem do postman? Com o resultado e a URL?

Comment: Coloquei um screenshot do Postman.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71404/discussion-between-perozzo-and-pnet).

Comment: Dá uma olhada no chat